# Trying to build a regular expression to check pattern - 2

Tags: regex, match

I was wondering if more checks could be added:  [Previously answered question](
[Trying to build a regular expression to check pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599725/trying-to-build-a-regular-expression-to-check-pattern)).

The above problem is brilliantly solved using this regex by Brian Rogers:

```
/^([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(-([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))?(,([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(-([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))?)*$/
```

**[For Reference, posting the older problem again]**

1. Start and end with a number
2. Hyphen should start and end with a number
3. Comma should start and end with a number
4. Range of number should be from 1-31
5. If a number starts with a hyphen (-), it cannot end with any other character other than a comma AND follow all rules listed above.

E.g.  `2-2,1` OR `2,2-1` is valid while `1-1-1-1` is not valid.

E.g.:
- 1-5,5,15-29
- 1,28,1-31,15
- 15,25,3 
- 1-24,5-6,2-9

**Could this go a step further and add other validations?**

1) The numbers should be in ascending order
E.g:
 - 1,2-3 - Valid
 - 4-6,23 - Valid
 - 23,4-5 - Invalid

2) The numbers should not repeat
E.g:
a) 2,2,2 - Invalid
b) 2,3-6,3 - Invalid
c) 2,5,7-20 - Valid

3) **If possible**
Number should not repeat if previously defined in range
E.g:
a) 2,3-6, 4 - Invalid, because 4 is already a number between 3 and 6
b) 12-16, 14-18 - Invalid, because 14,15 and 16 are already defined in 12-16
c) 9-13, 15, 17-19 - Valid

Comment: No - you're starting to ask questions that depend on the *interpretation* of particular character sequences (e.g. that 3-6 represents the integers 3, 4, 5 and 6). You can't deal with such things in a regex.

Comment: May be you'll find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907019/how-to-reduce-lists-of-ranges) usefull


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907019/how-to-reduce-lists-of-ranges

Comment: @M42 - for links in comments, put text in square brackets (`[]`), and then the URL immediately after in round brackets (`()`), E.g. `[this question](http://somewhere)`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever:I was trying to put this as an answer, but it came in comments, I don't know why :(, now it's too late to edit comment.

Comment: Could you mark the previous question as answered ?

Comment: As Damien said, regexes are not made to solve that kind of problem. They work on the lexical level, not the semantic level (the space of values). If you have semantic rules to check, parse the regex to extract numbers and ranges, and then with a bunch of code check the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression is supposed to check a pattern and not to handle business logic. The moment you start stating your problem with "if ... then ... else", it's not something regular expression is supposed to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are very powerful and can potentially be used to solve the kind of challenge you have - even implementing some kind of business logic validation.

From an architectural and software engineering point of view, I would recommend you to restructure the problem and use rather program code to solve the issue. Let me explain why: The code will get

- very difficult to read and understand
- error prone and not easy to test
- the cost of maintaining it will skyrocket

To summarize, even though regex are very powerful ( I am heavily using them as well in my applications) I would not overdo it. They are very elegant to solve some problems but get get very ugly to solve simple things.